# c# api methods created dynamically

Tags: c#, api, crud

Just as the title states, is it possible to create an api dynamically? I did some research and couldn't find any way of doing this. I have a method that pulls the columns in a table. I want to create all the CRUD operations from that pull of information. Those operations would then be able to be called through an API. Let me know if I am unclear or I need to post anything else.

Comment: Do you want to do it completely dynamically? By this I mean that it is generated at runtime. Or that you do code generation first and generate static code that is compiled after. By api you mean WebApi or just a library?

Comment: I mean a webapi,I would think it would be the former and generate at run time in case the information in the db changes. If i need to do the code generation first then I would do that, Please let me know if I need to clarify more please. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Code generation first I think is easier than generating all at runtime. Just another clarification Do you want to generate all the controllers with all the methods from the database or you need just the model to dynamically change and reflect the model in the database. By this I mean that you have a static controller for each table and if you add or remove a column the api will automatically also add or remove it to the output.

Comment: Probably to generate all the controllers with all the methods from the database. I do not believe I will be able to generate the static controller ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution to do it using T4 templates to generate code. T4 templates are available out of the box by Visual Studio. For more details check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017) about generating code with T4 Text templates.

For the sample I have created an include file Common.t4 that has the functions to retrieve model information. If you already have a library that does that you can import the assembly directly in the template and don't need also a common code file. I return only static data in the functions for simplicity you have then to implement it by calling your method that gets you the data.

Sample common file:

```
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#+
public string[] GetEntities()
{
    // TODO: implement logic to get entitities
    return new string[] { "Entity01", "Entity02", "Entity03" };
}
public class FieldDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
public FieldDefinition[] GetEntityFields(string entityName)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieval of Entity fields
    return new FieldDefinition[] 
    { 
        new FieldDefinition() { Name = "Id", Type = typeof(int) },
        new FieldDefinition() { Name = "Name", Type = typeof(string) }
    };
}
#>
```

Once you have this common function you can create one T4 template file for the models and one for the controllers.

Here is a sample models template:

```
<#@ template hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="Common.t4" #>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
<#
foreach (string entity in GetEntities())
{
#>
    public class <#=entity#>Model
    {
<#
    foreach (FieldDefinition fieldDefinition in GetEntityFields(entity))
    {
#>
        public <#= fieldDefinition.Type.FullName#> <#= fieldDefinition.Name#> { get; set; }
<#
    }
#>
    }

<#
}
#>
}
```

And finally the Controllers template:

```
<#@ template hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="Common.t4" #>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
<#
foreach (string entity in GetEntities())
{
#>
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/<#=entity#>")]
    public class <#=entity#>Controller : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/<#=entity#>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<<#=entity#>Model> Get()
        {
            return new <#=entity#>Model[] { new <#=entity#>Model(), new <#=entity#>Model() };
        }

        // GET: api/<#=entity#>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public <#=entity#>Model Get(int id)
        {
            return new <#=entity#>Model();
        }

        // POST: api/<#=entity#>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]<#=entity#>Model value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/<#=entity#>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]<#=entity#>Model value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/<#=entity#>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }

<#
}
#>
}
```

There are also many other commercial and free code generation tools available. Check this link: [Comparison of code generation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_code_generation_tools). This offers also alternatives to T4 if you don't like it or you are missing some feature.

In the end I also mention the technologies you can use for fully dynamic code generation in the runtime. For such a scenario you can use [Roslyn compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), [CodeDOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-source-code-generation-and-compilation) or [Reflection.Emit](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570).